# Как отключить свайп по вертикали?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

```js
let touchstartX = 0;
let touchendX = 0;

function checkDirection() {
  if (touchendX < touchstartX)
    document.getElementsByClassName("button-alert")[0].click();
  if (touchendX > touchstartX)
    document.getElementsByClassName("button-alert")[1].click();
}

var bb = document.getElementById("blue-bar");

bb.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
  touchstartX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
});

bb.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
  touchendX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
  checkDirection();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

#blue-bar {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.button-alert {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <br />

    <div id="blue-bar"></div>

    <br />

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button-alert" onclick="alert('Left Button Pressed')">
        Left Alert
      </button>
      <button class="button-alert" onclick="alert('Right Button Pressed')">
        Right Alert
      </button>
    </div>

    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее описать ваш вопрос?

Comment: Есть ось X и Y, для оси X есть свайп, но он работает и для оси Y, поэтому я хочу отключить ось Y, а X оставить

Comment: попробуйте `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: не работает.  :с